# Pad within grouped dates in R

Tags: r, date, time-series, lubridate, padr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(padr)
df <- tibble(`Action Item ID` = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"),
             `Date Created` = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", 
                                        "2019-06-01", "2019-06-01",
                                        "2019-08-01", "2019-08-01")),
             `Date Closed` = as.Date(c("2019-01-15", "2019-05-31", 
                                        "2019-06-15", "2019-07-05",
                                        "2019-08-15", NA)),
             `Current Status` = c(rep("Closed", 5), "Open")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(`Action Item ID`, `Current Status`), 
               names_to = "Type",
               values_to = "Date")
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    `Action Item ID` `Current Status` Type         Date      
#>    <chr>            <chr>            <chr>        <date>    
#>  1 ABC              Closed           Date Created 2019-01-01
#>  2 ABC              Closed           Date Closed  2019-01-15
#>  3 DEF              Closed           Date Created 2019-01-01
#>  4 DEF              Closed           Date Closed  2019-05-31
#>  5 GHI              Closed           Date Created 2019-06-01
#>  6 GHI              Closed           Date Closed  2019-06-15
#>  7 JKL              Closed           Date Created 2019-06-01
#>  8 JKL              Closed           Date Closed  2019-07-05
#>  9 MNO              Closed           Date Created 2019-08-01
#> 10 MNO              Closed           Date Closed  2019-08-15
#> 11 PQR              Open             Date Created 2019-08-01
#> 12 PQR              Open             Date Closed  NA
```

I've got my data frame above and I'm trying to pad dates within each group with the padr R package.

```
df %>% group_by(`Action Item ID`) %>% pad()
#> Error: Not all grouping variables are column names of x.
```

The error doesn't make much sense to me. I'm looking for output that would look like the following:

```
#> # A tibble: ? x 4
#>  `Action Item ID` `Current Status` Type         Date      
#>  <chr>            <chr>            <chr>        <date>    
#>  ABC              Closed           Date Created 2019-01-01
#>  ABC              NA               NA           2019-01-02
#>  ABC              NA               NA           2019-01-03
#>  ...              ...              ...          ...
#>  ABC              Closed           Date Closed  2019-01-15
#>  DEF              Closed           Date Created 2019-01-01
#>  DEF              NA               NA           2019-01-02
#>  ...              ...              ...          ...
#>  DEF              NA               NA           2019-05-30
#>  DEF              Closed           Date Closed  2019-05-31
#>  GHI              Closed           Date Created 2019-06-01
#>  ...              ...              ...          ...
```

Anybody have any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `padr` but if you change your column names to syntactically valid ones, i.e. "action_item_id", then it works. So maybe a tidyeval problem under the hood? `df %>% janitor::clean_names() %>% group_by(action_item_id) %>% pad()
` has warnings about NAs but no errors

Comment: @camille and that solves the mystery. Nice detective work.

Comment: The error message you posted tipped me off that column names were getting lost somewhere. Perfect example of how including error messages makes it easier to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?pad`, there is a `group` argument

> group - Optional character vector that specifies the grouping variable(s). Padding will take place within the different groups. When interval is not specified, it will be determined applying get_interval on the datetime variable as a whole, ignoring groups (see last example).

So, it is better to make use of that parameter

```
library(dplyr)
library(padr)
df %>% 
   pad(group = "Action Item ID")
# A tibble: 233 x 4
#  `Action Item ID` `Current Status` Type         Date      
#   <chr>            <chr>            <chr>        <date>    
# 1 ABC              Closed           Date Created 2019-01-01
# 2 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-02
# 3 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-03
# 4 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-04
# 5 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-05
# 6 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-06
# 7 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-07
# 8 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-08
# 9 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-09
#10 ABC              <NA>             <NA>         2019-01-10
# … with 223 more rows
```